# rails 3 making a <tr> onclick do the same ajax as a :remote => true link

Tags: javascript, jquery, ruby-on-rails, ajax

The question title pretty-much says it all. Basically i'm trying to get each of a table's tr elements to execute the same onclick ajax behaviour as a :remote=>true link would. It seems it would be a simple thing, but i just can't get my head round which way to approach it!

FYI, here's an example of a link that i would want to emulate inside a tr:

```
link_to "link text here", stream_item, {:remote => true, "data-toggle" => "modal", 'data-target' => "#commentModal"} %>
```

I guess the approach is either by only using jquery somehow, or something like:

```
<tr onclick="some stuff here">
```

Any pointers massively appreciated..

Thanks!

Comment: Seems to work fine here... What version of ruby and rails are you using? And what is the generated html?

Comment: looks like i've not explained myself very well - the link works fine. i'm trying to find out what i can add inside a <tr> tag to make the tr itself display the same behaviour. something like <tr onclick="some stuff here maybe">

Answer (score 0):

I'm guessing that you want to be able to click on the whole table row, not just the text link.  In that case, you'll have to employ JS event handlers as you guessed.

```
  $('#myrow').click(function() {
      $('#mymodal).show();
  });
```

And then assign the id:

```
<tr id="#myrow">Link Text</tr>
```

Comment: hi thanks for this - this will make the modal box appear, but how do i then activate the ajax part to load the right content inside the box?

Comment: Make it part of the `click` function.

    $('#myrow').click(function() {
      $.get('/myajaxurl');
      $('#mymodal).show();
    });

In this example, `/myajaxurl` hits your controller which responds to JS and triggers a view.  See also: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10565820/pre-render-ajax-populated-view-in-a-dry-way/